# How to execute command lines TestCafe in a project with Cucumber JS?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cucumber, cucumberjs, testcafe

I´m using Cucumber Js in a TestCafe project. I want to execute the cucumber feature and use testcafe's record function.

In a TestCafe I execute tests with the command line interface "testcafe chrome test.js --video artifacts/videos".

When use Cucumber Js execute with the command line interface "cucumber-js features/my_feature.feature".

Does anyone know what the CLI would look like?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, it's not possible to use TestCafe CLI to run CucumberJS tests. Current TestCafe-Cucumber integrations use TestCafe API to translate Cucumber feature files to TestCafe actions and heavily integrate into CucumberJS. [Issue #2835](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2835) will enable running CucumberJS tests from TestCafe CLI out of the box.

Comment: In this case what do I need to do to be able to run the test through CucumberJS and use TestCafe video?

Comment: You need to specify the video recording parameters at https://github.com/rquellh/testcafe-cucumber/blob/master/features/support/hooks.js#L30.